# How to show that a periodic Digraph does not have a synchronized coloring?

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Show that a periodic digraph does not have a synchronized coloring.

I tried to proceed with contradiction. Suppose that the digraph $D$ is periodic and contains a synchronized coloring. Then there exists a partition $\{V_1,V_2,...,V_{k}\}$ such that for every arc $(u,v)$ if $u\in V_i$ then $v\in V_{i+1}$. Also since there is a synchronized coloring, this implies that for every vertex $v\in D$ there exists a string $s_v$ such that on applying this string to every vertex $u\in D$ results in a $u-v$ walk or $u=x_0,x_1,...,x_t=v$. If $u\in V_m$ then $x_1\in V_{m+1}$ and so on. I am guessing that we have to show $u$ would lie in some other partition, which will be desired contradiction. However, I am not sure how I should proceed. Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

The following extracts will be helpful, for those interested in the problem:
[image][image]

Comment: Can you explain what "periodic" and "synchronized" means here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think that the added information should work....

Comment: @HenningMakholm please let me know if there is any other detail required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly (cannot open your additional information) it is fairly stright forward.

For a synchronized coloring you need for every vertex $v$ a word $w$, such that starting at any vertex, follwing the word $w$ you reach $v$.

Now assume your graph is periodic with period $k>1$, i.e. all cycles have multiples of $k$ as lengths.

In such a graph you find a vertex such that you cannot reach $v$ by following $w$ as follows:

Start at $v$ and proceed randomly $(-\text{length}(w)-1) \text{ mod } k$ steps and reach $v'$. Due to the periodicity, you cannot reach $v$ from $v'$ in $k$ steps for the following reason:

If you follow the word $w$ from $v'$ and end up at $v''$, you perform $\text{length}(w)$ steps. Hence from $v$ you reach $v''$ in a number $s$ steps, with $s \equiv -1$ mod $k$. Due to the periodicity $v$ cannot be equal to $v''$, as every closed loop has a multiple of $k$ as its length.

Comment: What do you mean by $\text{length}(w)$?

Comment: Is it the degree of vertex $w$

Comment: No, the length of the word $w$

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks....

Comment: I did not get the last line. Could you please explain?

Comment: Added the explanation of the last step